# pressing on button then download csv file

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a code where i need to login into a website and after i login i press on a certain button then download the csv file. The code worked with me when I pressed on another button. However I need to press on that certain button where it includes all the data i need in the csv file and it doesn't click or give me any errors. anyways here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import re
chromedriver = "/webdrivers/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://user.sensogram.com/signin')   #driver.get(url)-- We get 
url by using driver which we initialy load.    
print ("Opened sensogram")
time.sleep(5)    #Just wait for sometime.
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='usernameSignIn']")#Find 
email textaera.
email.send_keys('*****')  #Send email to this text area. 
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='passwordSignIn']") 
#Find password textarea.
password.send_keys('*****')   #send password to the password field.
button_to_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@ng- 
click='submitted=true']")  #Find login button.
button_to_login.click()      #Click on login button.
time.sleep(5)
Custom_Graph_Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='link_title' 
and contains (text(),'Custom Graph')]").click()
time.sleep(5)
while True:
if EC.element_to_be_clickable:
    try:
        csv_file_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[name()='tspan' and .='Download CSV']"))).click() #find the download button by Xpath of the HTML then click on Download CSV button
        print("\n Button is Clicked")
        time.sleep(5) #download every 1 minute
        #print(csv_file_button)
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
        time.sleep(10)
    continue
else:
    pass
```

The button that includes all the data I need is the custom graph button I was able to click on it but what I am stuck on now is pressing the CSV file button. Can someone help please!!! and am new in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `WebDriverWait` to `find_elements_by_class_name` to find all the buttons that contain `class` "highcharts-button".

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

path = "/webdrivers/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://user.sensogram.com/signin')   #driver.get(url)-- We get url by using driver which we initialy load.
print ("Opened sensogram")
time.sleep(5)    #Just wait for sometime.
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='usernameSignIn']")#Find email textaera.
email.send_keys('username')  #Send email to this text area.
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='passwordSignIn']")
#Find password textarea.
password.send_keys('password')   #send password to the password field.
button_to_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@ng-click='submitted=true']")  #Find login button.
button_to_login.click()      #Click on login button.
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='link_title' and contains (text(),'Custom Graph')]").click()

# get all buttons and find one that has 'Download CSV' text

btns = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("highcharts-button")
for btn in btns:
    if btn.is_displayed() and btn.text == 'Download CSV':
        btn.click()

time.sleep(4)
driver.close()
```